# Innocent pop-ups and interstitials

Tags: seo, interstitial, pop-up

With the recent news of Goole planning to penalise pop-ups and interstitials on search result pages in Jan 2017, I became concerned as we often use Hotjar to create survey popups on some landing pages for CRO purposes.

Even though these pop-ups are not deceitful or malicious, could this become a negative impact for our SEO?

Comment: Pop-ups don't need to be deceitful or malicious... to be deemed undesirable to users.  They are annoying and dampen user experience period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If appearing on your mobile site, then yes, they may not rank as highly.

[Helping users easily access content on mobile](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html)

You can see with the examples they give, they don't mention if they are deceitful or malicious, simply that they obscure the content:

> Showing a popup that covers the main content, either immediately after the user navigates to a page from the search results, or while they are looking through the page.
>
> Displaying a standalone interstitial that the user has to dismiss
>   before accessing the main content.
>
> Using a layout where the above-the-fold portion of the page appears
>   similar to a standalone interstitial, but the original content has
>   been inlined underneath the fold.

To continue to have a pop up while avioding the penalty, you will need to use small smart style banners, such as the example they give:

> Banners that use a reasonable amount of screen space and are easily dismissible. For example, the app install banners provided by Safari and Chrome are examples of banners that use a reasonable amount of screen space.

[image]

Although this is only on mobile devices, you can still continue to show them on desktop. 
(Until they decide to penalise pop ups on desktop too)